# Visual studio 2012 says the build is successful but the project does not run displaying an error that project.exe file is not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to run the following .cpp code in visual studio 2012.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <math.h>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include "mesh.h"
#include "mesh.cpp"
#include "iterators.h"
#include "Point.h"
#include "HalfEdge.h"
#include "HalfEdge.cpp"
#include "Edge.h"
#include "Edge.cpp"
#include "Vertex.h"
#include "Vertex.cpp"
#include "Face.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace MeshLib;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{



if( strcmp( argv[1], "-test" ) == 0 )
{
for(int k=0;k<4;k++){//making subdivision 4 times 
CMesh mesh, mesh_new;

//MeshLib::CMesh mesh;
if(k==0)
mesh.read_m("bird_subdivision.m");  
//read into mesh (triangulated surface     with format .m)
else
mesh.read_m("temp.m");
//creating new mesh for storing the result temporarily.
//mesh.write_m("bird_subdivision_2.m");
int max_id=-1;
int max_fid=0;
int intial_vertex_count=0;
//vertex iterator
for( MeshVertexIterator viter( &mesh ); !viter.end(); viter ++ ) 
//vertex         iterator; go through each vertex of the mesh
{
CVertex *pV = *viter;
//updating the vertex id 
if(max_id < pV->id())
{
max_id=pV->id();
}

CMesh::tVertex tv=mesh_new.createVertex(pV->id());
tv->point() = pV->point();

}//end of vertex iterator
//write edge iterator
vector<int> new_Id ;
vector<CMesh::tVertex> new_Vertex;
int eid=0;
for(MeshEdgeIterator eiter(&mesh ) ; !eiter.end();eiter++)
{
//std::cout<<"inside:MeshEdgeiterator"<<"\n";

CEdge *ne = *eiter;//creating object for Edge
eid++;
ne->createId(eid);
CVertex *cv1=ne->halfedge(0)->target();
//CVertex *cv2=ne->halfedge(0)->ccw_rotate_about_target()->target();
CVertex *cv2=ne->halfedge(0)->he_next()->target();
CVertex *cv3=ne->halfedge(1)->target();
//CVertex *cv4 = ne->halfedge(1)->ccw_rotate_about_target()->target();
CVertex *cv4 = ne->halfedge(1)->he_next()->target();


//getting the new vertex  from the above 4 vertices

//coordinates for veretx cv1
double x1=cv1->point().v[0];
double y1=cv1->point().v[1];
double z1=cv1->point().v[2];

//coordinates for veretx cv2
double x2=cv2->point().v[0];
double y2=cv2->point().v[1];
double z2=cv2->point().v[2];

//coordinates for veretx cv3
double x3=cv3->point().v[0];
double y3=cv3->point().v[1];
double z3=cv3->point().v[2];

//coordinates for veretx cv3
double x4=cv4->point().v[0];
double y4=cv4->point().v[1];
double z4=cv4->point().v[2];
//coordinates for point
double xa=(3*x1+x2+3*x3+x4)/8;
double ya=(3*y1+y2+3*y3+y4)/8;
double za=(3*z1+z2+3*z3+z4)/8;

//getting the edge pair
//if(ne->halfedge(0)->target()>ne->halfedge(0)->source())
//cout<<s<<"\n";
//creating new vertex
CPoint *point = new CPoint(xa,ya,za);


CVertex *tv= mesh_new.createVertex(++max_id);
tv->point()=*point;
tv->id()=max_id;
new_Id.push_back(eid);
new_Vertex.push_back(tv);
}//end of edge iterator;
//write a face iterator

for(MeshFaceIterator fiter(&mesh); !fiter.end();fiter++)
{
CFace *cface=*fiter;
CVertex  *cv1,*cv2,*cv3;

//get the vertex from face
cv1 = cface->halfedge()->target();
cv2= cface->halfedge()->he_next()->target();
cv3 = cface->halfedge()->he_next()->he_next()->target();    


int e1 = cface->halfedge()->edge()->getId();
int e2= cface->halfedge()->he_next()->edge()->getId();
int e3 = cface->halfedge()->he_next()->he_next()->edge()->getId();

int id1=cv1->id();
int id2=cv2->id();
int id3=cv3->id();

//getting three new vertices
CVertex *tv12, *tv13, *tv23;
tv12 = new_Vertex[find(new_Id.begin(), new_Id.end(), e2) - new_Id.begin()];
tv13 = new_Vertex[find(new_Id.begin(), new_Id.end(), e1) - new_Id.begin()];
tv23 = new_Vertex[find(new_Id.begin(), new_Id.end(), e3) - new_Id.begin()];

//creating four faces in every face that already exists
CVertex *v1[3];
v1[0]=mesh_new.idVertex(id1);
v1[1]=tv12;
v1[2]=tv13;
mesh_new.createFace(v1,++max_fid);

CVertex *v2[3];
v2[0]=tv13;
v2[1]=tv12;
v2[2]=tv23;
mesh_new.createFace(v2,++max_fid);

CVertex *v3[3];
v3[0]=tv23;
v3[1]=tv12;
v3[2]=mesh_new.idVertex(id2);

mesh_new.createFace(v3,++max_fid);

CVertex *v4[3];
v4[0]=tv13;
v4[1]=tv23;
v4[2]=mesh_new.idVertex(id3);
mesh_new.createFace(v4,++max_fid);

}

if(k<3)
{
int count=0;

//vertex iterator
for( MeshVertexIterator viter1( &mesh ); !viter1.end(); viter1 ++ ) 
//vertex     iterator; go through each vertex of the mesh
{
CVertex *pV1 = *viter1;
count++;

}//end of vertex iterator
mesh_new.write_m("temp.m"); //write the mesh
cout<<"Total no of vertices after iteraton"<<k+1<<"="<<count<<"\n";
}

else
{
int count=0;
//vertex iterator
for( MeshVertexIterator viter1( &mesh ); !viter1.end(); viter1 ++ ) 
//vertex     iterator; go through each vertex of the mesh
{
CVertex *pV1 = *viter1;
count++;

}//end of vertex iterator
mesh_new.write_m("result.m");
cout<<"Total no of vertices after iteraton"<<k+1<<"="<<count<<"\n";

}
}
}
//to read the character from the key board, here our main intention is     
to       keep the output screen until we enter a character
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

When i build the code, I get the following output:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: Modelrepair, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Then when I try to run the code, it says the project is out of date and would you like to build it. when I click yes,it gives the following error:

> Unable to start program "C:\Users\Hemanth\documents\VisualStudio 2012\Projects\Modelrepair\x64\Debug\Modelreair.exe"
>
> Cannot find the file specified.

I don't understand what the problem is. Please help.

Comment: Check if the output path from the linker matches the product output path. If they diverge you can get this error.

Comment: Well, the first thing to do is to check and see if the folder "C:\Users\Hemanth\documents\VisualStudio 2012\Projects\Modelrepair\x64\Debug\" contains a file named "Modelrear.exe". (Did you notice the difference in spelling between the executable name in the error message and the project name in the build message? "Modelrepair" != "Modelreair".)